# Spinner background too big

Tags: android, android-spinner

Our graphic designer sent me a PNG to put inside spinners of our app. But, the image appears too big in the phone. I could resize it, but due to different screen sizes, i don't think its a nice solution.

I did a spinner_selector.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/icono_desplegable_activar"
 android:state_enabled="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/icono_desplegable"
android:state_enabled="false" android:state_window_focused="false"/>
</selector>
```

And, then, in the layout:

```
<Spinner
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@id/textactivity"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:id="@+id/spinneractivity"
android:background="@drawable/spinner_selector"/>
```

How can I tell the spinner NOT to resize itself according to the image, but resizing the image to fit the spinner?

Thank you.

Comment: if you set height and width wrap_content it also considers background image size so you can use fixed value for height and width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 9 patch image as background of your spinner. If you can't use a 9-patch image, try setting the height and width attribute of the spinner to a fixed value.

Comment: I don't like the idea of fixed sizes in Android, but I guess its the only way, so I mark your answer as correct. Thanks for your help :)